# How to properly check disk usage on hdfs?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, namenode

I am running jobs on yarn and I see

```
Resources are low on NN.  Please add or free up more resources then turn off safe mode manually.
```

So, I go check disk space and I see that there is plenty of space:

```
df -h

Filesystem  Size     Used     Available  Use%  Mounted on
/dev/xvda1  5.0G     4.2 G    491 M      90%   /
tmpfs       30G      0        30 G       0%    /dev/shm
/dev/xvdb   53G      17 G     33 G       34%   /media/ephemeral0
```

So there is space.  What could be issue?

Comment: That shows space available on the data nodes. The error seems to tell the state of the namenode. On the namenode, see if you are running out of disk.

Comment: seems like there is plenty of space right?  Where do I look to find out the limits that it is exceeding?

Comment: Also, what does it mean to be "`Mounted on`"?

Comment: In your `hdfs-site.xml`, what is the value set for `dfs.namenode.name.dir`?

Comment: What does it mean to be `"Mounted on"`?

Answer (score 0):

> Resources are low on NN.

Your Namenode's local filesystem is running out of resources.

By default, `dfs.namenode.du.reserved` is configured as `104857600 bytes`. I.E., The mount point where the edits `dfs.namenode.name.dir` are being written should have atleast **`100MB`** of free space left. Check the disk space usage of the node.

```
df -h
```

Either free up the disk to have sufficient space or add more disk space to it. Then leave the `safemode`.

```
hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

Comment: yes, I checked that as well and it is at 90% when I check `df -h /` so there should be enough room?  I figured it was hdfs that was the problem because I saw that there was room.

Comment: No it is not HDFS. It is either your disk or memory. Can you post the output of `df -h`?